Analyze the contents of an environment only when it has been modified
Let's consider the following fictive piece of code which only contains data using a specific DSL.
\begin{myenv}
  a = 3 ;
  b = 3 ;
  c = a + b
\end{myenv}

I'm (re)working on L3 code that parses contents like myenv in order to construct several internal L3 variables for various further processing. To save time, I'd like to parse the content only if it's the first time or if the content has changed.
Is there a ready-to-use package to handle this, or do I need to start coding functionality myself via hashing?

I do not think there is anything in L3  there is a package memoize and also you can memoize using a lua library.They might be an overkill though. I would store the contents in a tlstart and only parse if tlcurrent is not equal to tlstart

The issue here as always is that stuff outside the environment can affect the typeset result

@JosephWright I have updated my question because the content of the env will be only data to be used later to do some formatting, for example, but also simple calculations.

the first time this compilation? the first time at all? memoize can certainly do this. it can also be made sensitive to changes outside the environment. but it works across different compilations. whereas storing it in a variable could obviously work within a compilation (or within a compilation, too).

@cfr Thanks for the advice. I will play more concretely on this as soon as possible.
